# How to implement ids.xml file as it shown in Google Developers guide?

Tags: android, xml, google-play, google-play-services

I am trying to upload my libGDX game to google play store but although it just took mine 3 days to develop the game I am unable to setup google play services almost for one week now. First of all please excuse my ignorance but I just don't understand this [modify your code](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#step_3_modify_your_code) section. Don't think I didn't search for it yet again I couldn't understand these:

**1)** Open res/values/ids.xml and replace the placeholder IDs. If you are creating an Android game from scratch, you will need to create this file first.

a) Specify your application ID in the app_id resource.

b) Specify each achievement ID that you created earlier in the corresponding achievement_* resource.

c) Specify each leaderboard ID that you created earlier in the corresponding leaderboard_* resource.

**2)** Open AndroidManifest.xml and enter your package name in the package attribute of the `<manifest>` element. If you are creating an Android game from scratch, make sure that you also add the following code inside the `<application>` element:

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Firstly, I created ids.xml file however, what is this placeholders id's that I should replace? There is no such thing like that.

Secondly my game doesn't have an ID. What is this app_id resource that I should specify? Where am I going to specify it? Is it something like this `<item name="app_id" type="id"/>`

Thirdly, game is maybe too simple so that there's no achievement nor leader board. Do I have to add these things that I really don't know at all?

Lastly, `android:value="@string/app_id"` gives error. Is it because I am unable to create ids.xml file properly or do i have to add something to strings value?

I just started developing apps for Android. My question is probably too easy that I shouldn't even ask it at the first place. But I believe if you help me with this it would be a fantastic guide for people who just started developing games. Any help will be very much appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that you are following the wrong guide in setting up Google Play Services. This is the guide on [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). What you are doing above is the guide for creating games using the Play Services which an API for creating games, but since you mentioned that you already have developed your game you don't need this and you only need to set up Google Play Services.

Comment: @gerardnimo First of all thank you for your answer. The link you shared turned out what I supposed to look for at the first place. You make me realize that I don't actually need to implement all that stuff :D If you send your comment as an answer I'll check it.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are following the wrong guide in setting up Google Play Services. This is the guide on [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). What you are doing above is the guide for creating games using the Play Services which an API for creating games, but since you mentioned that you already have developed your game you don't need this and you only need to set up Google Play Services.